# How to I suppress Texmaker's autocomplete?

Tags: texmaker

I have to use LaTeX for my degree and the system we get is Texmaker. I can't install an alternative.

I use `\par` for carriage return in my texts, and Texmaker always changes it to `\paragraph{*}` and puts the cursor between the brackets unless I forcibly suppress it using the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

It's cumbersome. What do I do when I just want `\par` and nothing else?

Comment: please don't use `\par` blank line is better (unless necessary)

Comment: When you say you 'can't install an alternative' what do you mean? LaTeX can be written in any text editor you want, it's just plain text. (There are a few caveats, if you want to use unicode input, for example, you need an editor that supports this, but the point stands). You could even use Notepad if you really wanted to. Obviously, you shouldn't do this. But you could.

Comment: What I mean is, I use it exclusively on the University system as the editor we're given and, as a student, I don't have the permissions to install an alternative.

In other words, I meant what I wrote, I literally cannot install an alternative. Not, at least, insofar as alternative dedicated LaTeX systems on the University computers are concerned.

Answer (score 3):

Options->Configure Texmaker->Editor-> Uncheck 'Completion'.

**Edit:**

I'll admit I didn't read the details of your question at first. The sequence above will disable all completion. If you only want to suppress the `\paragraph` completion when you want `\par` you'll have to add `\par` to the completion library. To do that go User->Customize Completion-> Enter \par and click 'Add' then 'OK'.

Comment: I don't have the reputation to +1 your response, but thanks, it's very helpful.

Comment: It would be cool if there is an option to disable only few of these suggestions for autocompletion. For example, I don't use \citep{} at all, but use \cite{}. Unfortunately, cite{} comes below \citep{} in suggestions, as a result, I have to press the down arrow many times to get what I want. It's very nice that they have given an option to add new user completions, but I couldn't find any way to remove or disable the default ones.